# Setting new user passwords in Apex

Tags: apex, user-management, dml, passwords, login-errors

I have a method that creates a new user and sets a custom password, everything works fine to the point where I try to log in with the new user and get an error that the login details are incorrect. Even the login history for that user does not show any entry stating that the password was incorrect, etc.

I have verified that the username and password both are correct, and it works when I do a subsequent setPassword() using the console.

Example:

```
User newUser = New User();
//...set user fields
insert newUser;    

String password = getPassword(8);
system.setPassword(newUser.Id, password);
//...email user the password
```

When I run this in the console the same problem occurs:

```
User u = new User();

u.username = 'test@test.com';
u.email = 'test@test.com';
u.lastName = 'test';
u.firstName = 'test';
u.alias = 'test1236';
u.languagelocalekey = 'en_US';
u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
u.profileId = '00eG0000000FgyJ';
insert u;

system.setPassword(u.id, 'testpassword1');
```

***UPDATE**

I can login after 5 minutes or so after the user is created, I have tried on two different orgs.

Comment: Does the debug log show any errors?

Comment: I recreated and did not have this problem. Is this code inside a try block that might be hiding an error?

Comment: Are you trying to login to https://test.salesforce.com or https://login.salesforce.com.  If you are in a sandbox you need https://test.salesforce.com.

Comment: Nope, no errors and this is in a dev org. The user is created and active this is what I have used in the console: 
`User u = new User();

u.username = 'testt99@test.com';
u.email = 'testt99@test.com';
u.lastName = 'test';
u.firstName = 'test';
u.alias = 'test1236';
u.languagelocalekey = 'en_US';
u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
u.profileId = '00eG0000000FgyJ';
insert u;

system.setPassword(u.id, 'testtest1');`

Comment: If you aren't seeing anything in the login history for the user, then it makes me think the user id you are trying to login with doesn't match the user.

Comment: I was just able to use the credentials you posted to login as the test user. It asked me to change the password, but it does work. (I didn't change the password or move on past that point.)

Comment: And I think it goes without saying that you should deactivate that user since you posted real credentials. :-)

Comment: I have :) Maybe somethings wrong with my browser, will empty the cache...

Comment: Can you try setting or check "Active" flag as true before logging in.

Comment: looks like it works when I wait for about 5 minutes after the user is created, the user is definitely active.

Comment: When I try to login right after the user is created is just throws an error, but if I wait for 5 minutes I logs me in and I get the change password page, hmm...

Comment: Is your User creation code in a `@future` method...that would explain the delay. Asking, because I know that the User is a setup Object and the workaround for creating them when you create other Objects is to put their creation in a `@future` method.

Comment: The user creation method is a `@future` method, but here I am running the code in the console that should in return execute without delay, every time I create a new user I verify that it exists in the setup and then login, so the user record is definitely there when I try to login.

Answer (score 11):

The authentication mechanism seems to have a replication delay. Changing your user name results in an email being sent to you:

> Dear Mr. User,
>
> Your username has changed.
>
> New username: ABC
>
> Old username: XYZ
>
> The new username may take several minutes to become fully functional.
>   We recommend you log in with the following link for the next 24 hours
>   to avoid problems.
>
> https://na1.salesforce.com/?c=...
>
> If you can't click the link, please copy and paste it into your
>   browser.
>
> Thank you, salesforce.com

I suspect that this same issue occurs when creating a new user; the user is only able to log in immediately because of the magic link they are sent in a new user email. When creating the user through other means, they will most likely experience a delay before they are able to log in using the provided user name.